# .htaccess rewrite for specific browser/operating-system combination

Tags: apache, .htaccess, google-chrome, browser, operating-system

I need to redirect if the user is accessing the site using **Chrome OS X**, but not **Chrome Windows** or any other OS - and the same for Safari.

Can I detect, specifically, **Chrome OS X** and ignore **Chrome Windows**? I *think* these are the user-agents for the two:

```
Chrome, MAC OS
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_7) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.91 Safari/534.30

Chrome, Windows 2008
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.91 Safari/534.30
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond):

```
RewriteModule On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Mac\ OS\ X.*Chrome
RewriteRule .* /path/to/something [L,R]
```

Comment: Perfect! I just needed to know to use \ - I'm useless, thanks!